# Godaddy - Office365 SMTP does not work?

Tags: php, email, smtp, office365

I'm using PHPMailer and have tried others but this simply does not work. I keep getting an error that the server keeps denying me access? Here is the example code used:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use    SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xx@xx.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxx';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I'm using the same settings as shown in their official documentation: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

What seems to be an issue? I have checked online in a number of posts but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas??

Comment: full error please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office365 via GoDaddy SMTP does not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089257/office365-via-godaddy-smtp-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

on a economic hosting smtp will not work, Please follow the mail driver solution listed below

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=mail
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=office365_email
    MAIL_PASSWORD=office365_password
    MAIL_FORM=office365_email
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

The mail could take about 2-5 minutes to deliver, but it's the working solution.
Thanks