# How to configure emails on laravale and godaddy with Microsoft365

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have godaddy server and Microsoft365 email on the local host it is sending emails but on the Sarver it gives me this error:

Unable to connect with STARTTLS:

stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer

certificate

CN=`*.prod.sxb1.secureserver.net' did not

match expected

CN=`smtp.office365.com'

This is my setting in .env:

## SMTP Settings

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_MAILER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=EMAIL

MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=EMAIL

MAIL_FROM_NAME="Learn Gate"

I added all DNS RECOREDS, I tried to use

STARTTLS, SSL, TLS
AND CHANGE MAILING host to secureserver.net configuration still the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office365 via GoDaddy SMTP does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089257/office365-via-godaddy-smtp-does-not-work)

Comment: I think that your problem is similar to which is discussed in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688060/laravel-9-error-laravel-email-unable-to-connect-with-starttls-stream-socket-e